# ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-01034, ora-27101

I am getting the above error when trying to connect to a server database from a client using service name `orcl`. It is getting connected when I am using the other service name i.e. `dms`

Below is my `listener.ora`

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = dms)
      (SERVICE_NAME = dms)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
#      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  (SID_DESC =
     (SID_NAME = orcl)
     (SERVICE_NAME = dms)
    # (GLOBAL_DBANME = orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
   #  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  )
  )


LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.53)(PORT = 1521))

    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /home/oracle/app/oracle
and tnsnames.ora
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.53)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     #(SERVICE_NAME = orcl.localdomain)
      (ORACLE_SID = dms)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

DMS =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.53)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = dms)
      (ORACLE_SID = dms)
    )
  )
```

Please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 101):

Open command prompt and execute the below commands:

```
set oracle_sid=DATABASE NAME
sqlplus /nolog
conn sys/sys as sysdba
shutdown abort
startup
```

Comment: Can you help me with the same set of commands in Linux? I'm using RHEL.

Comment: @EKta: for linux: just use `export ORACLE_SID=<your database name>` instead and the rest is the same

Comment: why is it that when I am trying to connect with 'connect' cmd, I am getting ORA-27101, but when I am doing conn sys/sys as sydba then I am able to connect??

Answer (score 37):

Sometimes, the database will not be mounted correctly, so we need to mount it manually. For that, shut it down and start it up then mount. Log in as oracle user, then run the following commands:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba;
shutdown immediate;
startup nomount;
alter database mount;
alter database open;
```

Comment: mount then flashback to a previous restore point fix it for me

Answer (score 9):

```
SQL> sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
SQL> startup

      Oracle instance started
      ------
      Database mounted.
      Database opened.

SQL> Quit

[oracle@hcis ~]$ lsnrctl start
```

Comment: `startup` does not seem to work, seems db setup issue
`SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1/dbs/initxe.ora'`

Comment: For a newly installed Oracle 19c Database before creating any database for use, this is what helped start my database. I had not noticed that I hadn't started it and was wondering where the ORA-01034 was coming from.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID are correct
To see the current values in windows, at the command prompt type

```
echo %ORACLE_HOME%
```

Then

```
echo %ORACLE_SID%
```

If the values are not your current oracle home and SID you need to correct them. This can be done in Windows environment variables.

Check out  [this page for more info](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_27101_shared_memory_realm_does_not_exist.htm)

Comment: This answer was close enough trigger my solution.  Although my $ORACLE_HOME & $ORACLE_SID variables were correct, my process was evoking a parameter file with that called the wrong SID.

Answer (score 4):

ORA-01034 and ORA-27101 normally indicate that the database instance you're attempting to connect to is shut down and that you're not connected as a user who has permission to start it up.  Log on to the server 192.168.1.53 and start up the `orcl` instance, or ask your DBA to do this for you.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue on windows XP. Resolved.
The error was caused due to the system log being full. 
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event viewer
Right click on application log, clear all events, optionaly save the log.
Same process for system log.
Restart and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

This same error occurred to me even though the `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` seemed to be correctly set up.

The problem was in `ORACLE_HOME`, which is not supposed to end with a slash character. When I removed the ending slash, it started to work properly.

```
# ❌ INCORRECT
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/oracle/11gR2/

# ✔️ CORRECT
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/oracle/11gR2
```

So, even if it seems everything is configured fine, check your variables for this.

Answer (score 3):

Run in cmd:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba;
```

Then:

```
SQL> create pfile='c:/init.ora' from spfile;
```

Remove `sga_target` line in `init.ora` file, then:

```
SQL> create spfile from pfile='c:/init.ora';
SQL> startup;
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while creating the connection on SQLDeveloper "ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist"

Solution:

1.Update the listene.ora file to include the SID.

```
  SID_LIST_LISTENER =
    (SID_LIST =
      (SID_DESC =
        (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
        (PROGRAM = extproc)
      )
      (SID_DESC =
        (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
        (PROGRAM = extproc)
      )
      (SID_DESC =
        ((GLOBAL_DBNAME = XE.DB)
        ((ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
        ((SID_NAME = XE)
      )
    )

  LISTENER =
    (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = USMUMTBALAKDAS2.us.deloitte.com)(PORT = 1521))
      )
    )

  DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

The Oraclexe directory may have the permission set to "[ReadOnly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAyVz.png)", Change the directory/sub-directory permission to read/write and restart the listener services.
Problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same `shared memory realm does not exist` symptom (on Windows) but for a different reason. I had just installed Oracle (XE) and after some troubleshooting, established that my installation was corrupt due to the presence of an ORACLE_HOME environment property at the time I installed it.

*If this is TLDR, skip to 'So to resolve:'!*

My initial symptom was:

```
Message 850 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL
```

Apparently the Windows install reads the ORACLE_HOME from the registry and doesn't need (and certainly in my case shouldn't have...) an environment property.

Remove it, as follows:

1. Edit the system environment settings (Windows key and start
   typing 'env' and you should see this option come up.
2. Delete any User and System Environment Variables called ORACLE_HOME, if
   present. (make a note of their values, mainly out of interest, but may be of
   use if you want to put them back for some reason!)
3. Restart your machine. Don't muck around with just a log off - restart your
   machine. The Windows Oracle install uses Windows services by default
   and your installation is currently very bad - it needs a restart.

Following the restart I was then able to get error messages other than 'No message file...' and could start looking at what the issue was.
Setting the ORACLE_SID to XE and connecting @XE I got as far as the errors in this page, namely the following symptoms:

```
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
```

Another symptom was:
When launching the 'Get started' page it failed to connect, giving a not found error (if I recall correctly), despite the Windows listener & XE services being started. As noted in another answer, this could be due to the windows services not being started. In my case those services were started, so something else was misconfigured.

At this point, I figured maybe my install had just gone so badly wrong due to the presence of my bad ORACLE_HOME environment property that I should reinstall. (Previous reinstalls hadn't helped, but those had all been before I noticed the ORACLE_HOME system environment property (probably set up by me a year ago!).

**So to resolve:**

1. Close any app looking at the Oraclexe install directory (editors/explorer/cmd prompts)
2. A quick trip to Add/Remove programs and uninstall OracleXe
3. Double-check you have no ORACLE_HOME environment property set anywhere, remember - Windows will use registry entries to get it.
4. Restart (take no chances - we're in this for the long term!)
5. Did you make sure there was no ORACLE_HOME property?
6. Run the Oracle installer again (as local admin account if applicable)
7. You should be able to rejoice in a working install. I did, at least!

Answer (score 1):

After wasting so much time i got to know that there was mistake in my syntax to connect with DB. I was using colon "**:**"  instead of slash "**/**".

(1) if you use sid below is the syntax to get connection:

```
**"jdbc:oracle:thin:@{hostname}:{port}:{SID}"**
```

(2) if you use service name, below is the syntax to get connection:

```
"**jdbc:oracle:thin:@//{hostname}:{port}/{servicename}**"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listener.ora is misconfigured. There is no orcl service.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have resolved your issue. If you still got issue then double check again if you install this Oracle under a domain account. I found a thread that says Oracle XE giving same error when installing under domain account. Please use a local account instead.

Source:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2141735?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

In my case here, I just had to resurrect a server that was 9 years old, and Oracle was giving me this error.

For some reason, the server had been renamed, but the `app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/network/admin/listener.ora` file was still declaring a LISTENER with the old HOST.

I had to put the same name that I had in `/etc/hostname` in the `/etc/hosts`, and also fix the name used in the `listener.ora`.

Answer (score 0):

Also try directly startup:

```
sqlplus /nolog
conn / as sysdba
startup
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue come up when attempting to start a `sqlplus` session like this:

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect user/password
```

The fix was to remove `/nolog` and to escape the `user/password`:

```
sqlplus 'user/password'
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL> sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

SQL> startup

```
  Oracle instance started
  ------
  Database mounted.
  Database opened.
```

SQL> Quit

I also got same problem.I tried above mentioned steps and
then it worked for me.You can try.

Comment: What does your answer add to existing identical answers?