# Oracle 11g XE ORA-01034 and ORA-27101 after multiple installation of 10 and 11 versions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

1. Windows 7 x64
2. Local instance of Oracle 11g XE

Hello, I'm new to Oracle. I have reinstalled oracle few times (version 10 and 11).

So I'm getting the following problems after installation
When I try to execute

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

I get ORA-12638 and the secod problem that I can't connect http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950 (on previous installation of Oracle 10g I was able to connect to it).

Than I fixed ORA-12638 by setting SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE) in sqlnet.ora file.

After this fix I successfully stoped and started database (OracleServiceXe)
Now After I use `sqlplus sys as sysdba` I get `(ORA-01031: insufficient privileges)`. 
So I'm trying to login as system. Now I get

```
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

So now I'm trying to fix this issue. I found out few tips that it might be related to ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID
So I added to Environment Variables following values

```
ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\
```

I checked it (echo %ORACLE_HOME% returns C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)

Also I run a command in terminal set `ORACLE_SID=xe` (and I aslo checked it returns xe)
After I restarted OracleServiceXe and tried again to login as system, but I get the same ORA errors (01034 and 27101)

**1 - Checked listener status**

```
C:\>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 06-╩┬▓-2017 12:16
:16

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                06-╩┬▓-2017 11:36:35
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 39 min. 43 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\IIAROSHENKO\listen
er\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=[IIAROSHENKO(host info)...])(PORT=15
21)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

**2 - Checked relevant services are started**
I restarted OracleServiceXE & OracleXETNSListener

**3 - Checked my path variable is correct**
I checked my enviromental variables (I have ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\ and int Path I also have C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;

**4 - My tsnnames.ora and listener.ora are** 
**tsnnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [IIAROSHENKO(host info)...])(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

**listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [IIAROSHENKO(host info)...])(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

**5 - Checked ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID in registry**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_XE
ORACLE_SID=XE
ORACLE_HOME=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
ORACLE_BASE=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle
```

**6 - Tried starting up the instance**

```
C:\>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on ╫Є. ╩т│ 6 12:42:09 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Enter user-name:
```

**7. In alert folder** C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\IIAROSHENKO\listener\alert I got few warnings "WARNING: Subscription for node down event still pending". I have only this alert folder. (I don't have log corresponing to [Oracle 11g XE - sudden ORA-01034: ORACLE not available and ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898392/oracle-11g-xe-sudden-ora-01034-oracle-not-available-and-ora-27101-shared-mem) part 8)

So I'm really confused with all this. I succesfully installed oracle at my home, so I think this issue might be related to installing and unistalling oracle 10 and 11 multiple times and it might something to do with  http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950 not started.

I tried to provide information accoring to this [Oracle 11g XE - sudden ORA-01034: ORACLE not available and ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898392/oracle-11g-xe-sudden-ora-01034-oracle-not-available-and-ora-27101-shared-mem) . And if anything is needed please tell me. But i didn't manage to find database log I tried to look at $ORACLE_BASE/diag but there is only tnslsnr folder in it and no rdbms folder. Thanks for your time and patience).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my colleage helped me with this issue. 
The solution was to unistall oracle, create a new user and grant him administrative rights(`computer -> manage -> Local Users and Groups -> Users -> add user`). To login as this user (.\user) and install oracle, after that enter with your own account. After that get started page started to work. I'm not very familiar with oracle, so I will read about this issue more, but for now I hope that this solution will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occured to me, tried everything but the solution was simple - date&time of my PC was not set correctly (an hour earlier), after changing Date&Time settings in BIOS reinstalled Oracle XE and everything was working!