# Error ORA-27101 with Debian and Oracle XE 11g

Tags: oracle, debian

I'm working on Debian 9.3 and Oracle XE 11g.

After the installation of Oracle XE 11g :

```
$ sudo service oracle-xe status
● oracle-xe.service - LSB: Oracle 11g Express Edition
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/oracle-xe; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2018-04-01 21:30:26 CEST; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1842 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/oracle-xe stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
  Process: 1893 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/oracle-xe start (code=exited, status=0/SUC

avril 01 21:30:25 pitcairn systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Oracle 11g Express Edition.
avril 01 21:30:25 pitcairn oracle-xe[1893]: Starting Oracle Net Listener.
avril 01 21:30:25 pitcairn su[1903]: Successful su for oracle by root
avril 01 21:30:25 pitcairn su[1903]: + ??? root:oracle
avril 01 21:30:25 pitcairn su[1903]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for us
avril 01 21:30:25 pitcairn oracle-xe[1893]: Starting Oracle Database 11g Express
avril 01 21:30:25 pitcairn su[1919]: Successful su for oracle by root
avril 01 21:30:25 pitcairn su[1919]: + ??? root:oracle
avril 01 21:30:25 pitcairn su[1919]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for us
avril 01 21:30:26 pitcairn systemd[1]: Started LSB: Oracle 11g Express Edition.
```

I have the follow error :

```
$ sqlplus SYSTEM
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sun Apr 1 20:19:33 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

An idea ? Thank you.

Comment: And there isn't a duplication of another question.
Because, I can't do that :

    set oracle_sid=DATABASE NAME
    sqlplus /nolog
    conn sys/sys as sysdba
    shutdown abort
    startup

First: I doesn't know the value of "DATABASE NAME".
Second, if I use the command sqlplus /nolog, I can't use the command conn sys/sys as sysdba because I haven't the necessery privileges.

$ sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sun Apr 1 20:32:59 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: ok, i've retracted my vote for duplication, but it seems interesting that you don't have credentials for `sys` but `system` ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555827/ora-01034-oracle-not-available-ora-27101-shared-memory-realm-does-not-exist

Comment: Read the first comment please, this is not a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555827/ora-01034-oracle-not-available-ora-27101-shared-memory-realm-does-not-exist