# allocate more storage to database in oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c, navicat

I am new to oracle and I am using oracle 19c. My problem is that I am getting "ora-27101:shared memory realm does not exist". I searched for it and the answers were that my database needs more storage. I used automatic memory shared management while creating the database and now I can not find how to fix this error and also allocate more storage to it. I have to insert large-size data into this database.
Also, I use Navicat to connect to my oracle 19c database. Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT:

I was trying to import data with Navicat to the database but when it passed 13% of the process, it froze on 13% and did not continue the process. So I canceled the process and closed the connection. Next time when I turned my PC on, I could not connect to the database anymore and got an ora-12514 error. To solve this problem I added this part of code to listener.ora(I just added the 2nd SID_DESC to SID_LIST_LISTENER which is related to my database):

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = E:\db_home)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:E:\db_home\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC=
      (SID_NAME = dbb034)
      (ORACLE_HOME= E:\db_home)
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DB_B034)
    )
  )
```

After adding this part, I now get error like this:

```
ora-01034:ORACLE not available
ora-27101:shared memory realm does not exist
process ID:0
Session ID:0 Serial Number:0
```

here is my last log from alert.log:

```
2021-05-03T17:56:53.567632+04:30
Errors in file E:\ORACLE19C\diag\rdbms\db_b034\dbb034\trace\dbb034_ora_3308.trc:
ORA-19809: limit exceeded for recovery files
ORA-19804: cannot reclaim 181511168 bytes disk space from 8657043456 bytes limit
NET  (PID:3308): Error 19809 Creating archive log file to 'E:\ORACLE19C\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\DB_B034\ARCHIVELOG\2021_05_03\O1_MF_1_53_%U_.ARC'
NET  (PID:3308): Stuck archiver: inactive mandatory LAD:1
NET  (PID:3308): Stuck archiver condition declared
2021-05-03T17:56:53.584640+04:30
Errors in file E:\ORACLE19C\diag\rdbms\db_b034\dbb034\trace\dbb034_ora_3308.trc:
ORA-16038: log 2 sequence# 53 cannot be archived
ORA-19809: limit exceeded for recovery files
ORA-00312: online log 2 thread 1: 'E:\ORACLE19C\ORADATA\DB_B034\REDO02.LOG'
USER (ospid: ): terminating the instance due to ORA error 
2021-05-03T17:56:53.785392+04:30
System state dump requested by (instance=1, osid=3308), summary=[abnormal instance termination].
System State dumped to trace file E:\ORACLE19C\diag\rdbms\db_b034\dbb034\trace\dbb034_diag_16284.trc
2021-05-03T17:56:54.275058+04:30
TT00 (PID:14380): Gap Manager starting
2021-05-03T17:56:57.492949+04:30
Instance terminated by USER, pid = 3308
```

Comment: Fijrst, you are confusing _storage_ (disk space), with _memory_.  Second, I'd seriously doubt that your reported error is due to lack of either.  I fear you are chasing a red herring.  exactly what were you doing to observe the reported error?  Please update your question to show the last startup sequence from your database alert log.

Comment: that usually means the db is not open/mounted

Comment: @EdStevens I added an edit part. Hope it can clarify the problem.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555827/ora-01034-oracle-not-available-ora-27101-shared-memory-realm-does-not-exist

Comment: @DaveCosta I can not connect to my database to shut down and start it up again. I get ora-12560 error. I do not know how should I connect to my database!

Comment: connect to the database instance (even if it is not started) with 'sqlplus / as sysdba'. From there you can check the status with 'select status from v$instance;'.  Please do so, and update your question with a formatted copy and paste of the result (please, no screen shots).  Also you ignored my previous request " Please update your question to show the last startup sequence from your database alert log."

Comment: @EdStevens I do not whether it is correct but it was the last log of my database. Also, I can not connect to my database. I now get ora-12560 error. I set oracle_sid to my database name and then try connect with sqlplus / as sysdba(also I tried with other users).

Comment: Ok, your alert log gives several error messages. What did you discover when you googled them?  One problem you have is that your archivelog destination is out of disk space.  When you run in archivelog mode (and if production, you _should_) then you need to regularly take rman backups of both the database and the archivelogs, and include the 'delete all input' option with the backup of archivelogs.

Comment: @EdStevens I resized my fast recovery area and now it's working. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, but if you aren't doing anything to keep your archivelogs cleaned out, you will just hit the same problem again.

Comment: @EdStevens yeah I cleaned them and also I turned auto-archive off to prevent the same problem. Is it ok if I write what did I do as an answer to my own question now? Or it is not legal?

Comment: If you worked out the answer yourself, it's perfectly fine to post it yourself. As for your 'solution', I'd point out that since you are writing the archlogs to the FRA, just deleting them by using OS commands will not help, because oracle will not update the FRA usage stats.  If you "turned auto-archive off"  (that is, put the db in NOARCHIVELOG mode, then your database is only recoverable to the point of your last _offline_ backup.  Ergo, you do not consider the databse to be very important.

Comment: @EdStevens I cleaned them with RMAN commands

Comment: _" I cleaned them with RMAN commands"_  in that case, the FRA accounting should reflect reality.  If you had deleted them with OS commands, the FRA would think they were still there and that that space was still consumed.